# Amending return to include Schedule B?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, fbar, amended-tax-return

I included and paid tax on the interest I earned in my foreign account as 1099-INT, but it didn't file a Schedule B or ask if I had foreign accounts.

Since the account has over $10k, I need to file an FBAR, but do I need to file amended 1040x returns just to check off the "yes" box in Schedule B Part 3? If so, for how many years do I need to amend the returns?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _If you had_ underpaid tax but not willfully and you live here, you would come under the [Streamlined Domestic Offshore program](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/u-s-taxpayers-residing-in-the-united-states) which is satisfied with 3 years amended returns, 6 years FBARs, and fixed 5% penalty. I don't know any regs that apply specifically to you, but it would seem inequitable to treat you worse than a non-payer. FWTW. Good luck.